# Fetch data from data.php and transfer into bargraph

Tags: javascript, chartjs-2.6.0

data.php where the data in JSON form

[image]

my visualization bargraph.html all master can see no date on that graph 
[image]

my app.js that fetch data from data.php and transfer into bargraph, but date are not inserted into bargraph - what am I doing wrong?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost/chartjs/data.php",
    method: "GET",
    success: function(data) {
      console.log(data);
      var incubator = [];
      var total = [];
      var calender = [];

      for (var i in data) {
        incubator.push("incubator " + data[i].incubatorid);
        calender.push("calender " + data[i].calender);
        total.push(data[i].total);

      }

      var chartdata = {
        labels: incubator,
        datasets: [{
          label: 'Total successfull egg hatch hahhaha ',
          backgroundColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.75)',
          borderColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.75)',
          hoverBackgroundColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 1)',
          hoverBorderColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 1)',
          data: total
        }]
      };


      var ctx = $("#mycanvas");

      var barGraph = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'bar',
        data: chartdata
      });
    },
    error: function(data) {
      console.log(data);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Recommended reading: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I would recommend reading the [help] before posting. It has a lot of good information about the guidelines of Stack Overflow along with suggestions about how to title your question properly and such. Currently it's very hard to understand what exactly you are asking. Reading the [help] and taking the time to write a detailed question that gives the relevant information will lead to better answers.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/bm/docs/Web/JavaScript

Comment: If the Ajax works, you can create a snippet with the relevant HTML canvas and example data. Click [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52934025/edit) and then the snippet editor `[<>]` and create a [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you want to do something that is not allowed by the library, the chart type **bar** only accepts `label`, `xAxisID` and `yAxisID` to print values on it, the other properties are just used for styling the chart.

You can see more details of this chart [here](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/bar.html#dataset-properties):